# Why does setting headers to 200 OK give 404 Not Found with scraping tools?

Tags: php, facebook, response-headers

This is on an old PHP version, 5.2.17 that one of my web hosts has. The following code is verified to be executed on page load, before headers are sent:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 OK");
```

However, using the Facebook Debugger and double-checking with [this alternative](https://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/header-checker/) gives a 404 error. Despite this, the page content is fetched and indexed OK by the scraper. Needless to say, I would like to not get a 404 reported to scrapers if the page loads correctly in all browsers, validates, and has correct headers.

One example is [this link](http://coppershade.org/articles/Code/Tools/AsmTwo/), which returns a 200, and

[the same URL (without trailing /)](http://coppershade.org/articles/Code/Tools/AsmTwo), which returns a 404.

**How do I accomodate SEF URLs with or without trailing slashes to be scraped correctly?** Although I doubt this is the problem, since Wikipedia links have no trailing slashes and report 200 OK.

Comment: http://coppershade.org/articles/Code/Tools/AsmTwo returns 404. Try from scratch and add stuff one thing at a time to find the point when it breaks.

Comment: _“old PHP version, 5.2.17”_ - that is the first thing you should get fixed; this version has been out of support for several years now already. Still running any website on that is rather irresponsible. http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for commenting. But how do I go from you agreeing with me that the host's PHP version is old to the cause of the problem? It's not like scrapers see anything but the output from whatever version.

Comment: Well you'd have to show us how you implemented those URLs in the first place ... likely not a problem of PHP version. _"and the same URL [...]"_ - well they aren't, they are two different URLs. Whether they should be _treated as_ the same and by whom/how, is up to you - implement a 301 redirect to the preferred version, set canonical/og:url, ...

Comment: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://coppershade.org/">` - that's wrong in any case of course, because by that you are telling Facebook that was the URL to fetch the OG meta data from.